# use of undeclared identifier 'temp'

Tags: c++, clang++

The below c++ code gives me error use of undeclared identifier 'temp'

/home/test/include/memory.h

```
#ifndef MEMORY_H
#define MEMORY_H

#if __ENABLE_MEMORY

__device__ int temp = 50;
extern "C" inline __device__ void* memory(){
     ...
     temp =  temp + 100;
     ...
}

#endif
#endif
```

/home/test/include/internal_memory.h

```
#ifndef INTERNAL_MEMORY_H
#define INTERNAL_MEMORY_H

#ifndef __ENABLE_MEMORY
#define __ENABLE_MEMORY 1
#endif

#if __ENABLE_MEMORY
extern "C" __device__ void* memory();
static inline __device__ void* call_memory(){ return memory();}
#endif

#include <memory.h> 
#endif
```

/home/test/main.cpp

```
 #include "internal_memory.h"
 ..
 .
 .
 void show(){
    std::cout << "temp is: " << temp << std::endl;
 }
 .
 .
 .
```

I m compiling the code with clang++  version 11.0.0.

clang --version looks as follows:

```
  clang version 11.0.0
  Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  Thread model: posix
  InstalledDir: /opt/rocm/llvm/bin
```

Im compiling the code as below.

```
  /opt/rocm/llvm/bin/clang++ -DDEBUG -D__x86_64__ -I/home/test/include -I/home/test -g -fPIC -std=c++14 -o main.o -c main.cpp
```

what am i missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Function `memory` has the `__device__` qualifier (I suppose you are compiling a CUDA program).

`memory` refers to `temp`, which is a global variable in host memory. You probably want `__device__ int temp = 50;`

To query `temp`, you would need to copy its value back to the host. Along the lines of

```
int host;
cudaMemcpy(&host, &temp, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Comment: sorry. i missed that __ device __ part.. edited the question. it gives me the error still.

Comment: You cannot directly read `__device__` variable from a host function `show`. The compiler is right to complain about this. For all intents and purposes, think that `__device__` part and non-`__device__` parts are on different machines entirely.

Comment: Added querying.

Comment: you mean the querying part should be in the host function show.  This part I can understand as host and device parts are different. But even if i add non device variable int temp1 in the same header, and try to access it in show, still i get the error. This is weird.

Comment: That's because `temp` is not declared in `internal_memory.h`. You are including a standard C include `memory.h`, when your intention is to probably `#include "memory.h"`. There is a subtle yet very important search path difference between `<memory.h>` and `"memory.h"`